# How do I specify the dimensions of the video (height, width) when sending telegrams by bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I use the `node-telegram-bot-api` library. How do I specify the size of the video when sending it?

```
// where to specify height and width ?
bot.sendVideo(
  chatId,
  video,
  { caption: 'my video' },
  { filename: 'my_file' }, 
)
```

The telegram API allows you to specify sizes, but it seems to me that the `sendVideo` method does not allow you to specify them. Is it so?

p.s.: I tried to pass height and width through the option argument.

```
bot.sendVideo(
    chatId,
    `video`,
    {
        caption: 'my video',
        height: 720,
        width: 1280
    },
    {filename:'my_file'}
)
    .then(res=>{console.log(res)})
```

but with any parameters of the height and width parameters, I get the same answer.

```
video: {
    duration: 8,
    width: 1080,
    height: 1920,
    file_name: 'my_video',
    mime_type: 'video/mp4',
    thumb: {
      file_id: '***',
      file_unique_id: '***',
      file_size: 12743,
      width: 180,
      height: 320
    },
    file_id: '***',
    file_unique_id: '***',
    file_size: 4938678
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the `node-telegram-bot-api` library's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/src/telegram.js#L909), you can see that the `sendVideo()` method accepts an `options` object as the third parameter that stores additional Telegram query options.

You're already passing down an object with a `caption` key and you could add some more there, like `height`, `width`, `duration`, etc. A complete list of these options is available on the [Telegram docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvideo).

```js
bot.sendVideo(
  chatId,
  video,
  {
    caption: 'my video',
    height: 720,
    width: 1280,
  },
  { filename: 'my_file' }, 
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but I have already tried to pass the parameters this way. It doesn't work, or I misunderstand how telegram resizes the video. I edited the question. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

I looked at the sources of the library, an object with parameters is simply sent to the telegram server. Maybe an object with parameters should look somehow different?

Comment: maybe telegram has some kind of limitation on the size of the video?

Comment: thanks. You spelled it right! You saved me.

Comment: So it did work? Great ;)

Comment: @vasya how did you get it to work?

Comment: @JosephCardwell I added another answer with the code that worked for me.
sorry for such a long wait....

Answer (score 1):

it will work, if you pass the video parameters to options params (the third parameter).

```
bot.sendVideo(
    chat_id,
    `${path_to_video}`,
    {
        width: width,
        height: height,
    }
)
```

I used the ["get-video-dimensions"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-video-dimensions) library so that the video does not change the original parameters.
Here is the final code that worked for me:

```
const getDimensions = require("get-video-dimensions");
getDimensions(`${path_to_video}`)
    .then( dimensions => {
        return bot.sendVideo(
            chat_id,
            `${path_to_video}`,
            {
                width: dimensions.width,
                height: dimensions.height,
            }
        )
    })
```